# How to get hyperlinked PHP value in other PHP file

Tags: php

I have a PHP page where I have hyperlinked text:

```
 echo "<li><a href=list_result2.php?name=$disease_name>$disease_name</a></li>";
```

Let I have 5 diseases in hyperlinked list, i.e. diabetes, Ischemic Stroke,
Cardiovascular Disease and malaria. Whenever I am clicking single word disease, say diabetes or malaria the output file is showing proper name but whenever I am clicking disease with more than one word it is showing only first word, not entire disease name. The output is as following in output file:

```
 In list_result2.php file Ischemic is clicked.
```

It should display **Ischemic Stroke**. Below is the second PHP file code snippet:

```
<?php echo "In list_result2.php file";
 $condition=$_GET['name'];
 echo "$condition is clicked";?>
```

Can anybody guide in how to get the entire name passed into my second php file.

Comment: replace space with `+`

Comment: Use ``urlencode($disease_name)`` in the link, then ``urldecode($_GET['name']`` on the second page.

Comment: @JoelHinz You don't need `urldecode`, PHP will do that automatically

Comment: @AleksG Thanks, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your hyper link like this

```
echo "<li><a href=list_result2.php?name=".urlencode($disease_name).">$disease_name</a></li>";
```

and change list_result2.php like this

```
<?php 
 $condition=urldecode($_GET['name']);
 echo "$condition is clicked";?>
```

Comment: Uhm... you didn't mean to put the function call inside the double quotes, did you?  Also, I don't think you need explicit `urldecode`.  Or did you simply copy @JoelHinz 's comment?

Comment: but the issue which is face by questioner is quite similar which can be solved using urlencode and urldecode.

Comment: Thanks Ram Sharma. It worked the way how I wanted, dots did the trick.

Comment: Again, you do not need to `urldecode` the `$_GET` variable.  PHP does that automatically.

Comment: You are right ALeks G. The code is working perfectly without **urldecode** .